# Can I off the ATS and upload application to App Store? - IOS 9

Tags: connection, app-store, ios9

I want to update the application to App Store and off the ATS.
Does Apple allow the application to off ATS and live to App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Apple allows temporary configuration to load insecure HTTP Arbitrary loads. You may opt out from ATS by following their official latest technote for [ATS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/).
You can also find examples for configuration as per your requirement [here](https://ioscuriosity.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/app-transport-security-in-ios-9/) and implement it in your project to publish it in AppStore.